# Without fixed width, place a center-aligned block with right-aligned text in a div

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Seems like all the solutions assume a fixed width, which is very bad when trying to do a responsive website.

I have a block of text in a div. The block itself should be centered in the div. This can be achieved with `text-align: center;`. But I want the text inside the block to be right-aligned.

**Here's an original code snippet:**

```
<div>
    <h3 class="quote-text">My awesome quote goes here.</h3>
    <h4 class="quote-author">– Me, Myself and ADTC</h4>
</div>
```

**Current Result:**

[image: screenshot of current result]

**Expected Result:**

[image: screenshot of expected result]

I tried placing the text block in a parent `span`, adding `margin: auto`, just plain `text-align: right`, etc. *Nothing worked so far.*

I don't want any solution that forces me to fix the width since I'm building a fluid layout. It would also be terrible to make JavaScript hacks to "update" the fixed width on window resize.

BTW, it's worth noting that the `div` shown above is `inside` a Bootstrap column as the column content. In the screenshot, the filler text is in the same column and comes before the `div`.

Comment: Is not neccesary `float` in this issue. With `text-align:right` should be working. OP doesn't share his code, doesn't provide a working example, so every solution here is totally especulation.

Comment: If you have no will to help, kindly stand aside and let those who are willing. I wouldn't ask if I could figure it out myself.

Comment: @randy ain't accepting yours anyway. What's with the hatred? Like I said I didn't downvote your answer. It was from someone else. PS: This kind of emotional responses and politics is what's making SO less useful than it could be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

**CSS**

```
div {
  text-align: center;
}

h3 {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: right;
}  

.intro {
  display: block;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <h3 class="quote-text">My awesome quote goes here.<span class="intro">– Me, Myself and ADTC</span></h3>   
</div>
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/luispa/gamge71q/12/)

Comment: That's good solution, but two things: OP can achieve the same without modify the HTML, and I think that `!important` it's not neccesary.

Comment: This is good enough, I guess. Just need to style the `span` correctly as I can't use `h4`. Thanks!